# Sqooping from oracle to hive is failing with an error

Tags: sqoop

I tried to sqoop a table from oracle to Hive, But when I issue a sqoop command it is able to connect the db and fetch the reocds, but while it is getting the meta data for creating a table in Hive it is failing with below exception. 
when I browse for this problem every one are saying it is some thing related to case sensitive issue, but I tried all the possibilities, but no solution at the end.

Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.sqoop.hive.TableDefWriter.getCreateTableStmt(TableDefWriter.java:175)
    at org.apache.sqoop.hive.HiveImport.importTable(HiveImport.java:187)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.importTable(ImportTool.java:425)
    at org.apache.sqoop.tool.ImportTool.run(ImportTool.java:502)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.run(Sqoop.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:70)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runSqoop(Sqoop.java:181)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:220)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.runTool(Sqoop.java:229)
    at org.apache.sqoop.Sqoop.main(Sqoop.java:238)
```

Comment: Please share entire Sqoop log generated with parameter --verbose.

Comment: Please find the sqoop log file at below location https://www.hightail.com/download/OGhlTG0zT2J3TGhwdmNUQw

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest filling bug on [SQOOP JIRA](http://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SQOOP) as this seems to me like a bug inside the Oracle Connector. Please attach the log to the JIRA when creating. In the mean time you can use OraOop connector or switch to Generic JDBC Connector instead.

Comment: I resolved this problem, this issue is because of incompatible version on ojdbc jar present inside sqoop lib folder. After changing the ojdbc version it is started working for me.